# Ruby - Steps in a Gem build process

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I build Ruby Gems frequently, and I'm looking to automate the build process of a Ruby gem. I realize, of course, that Ruby is not a compiled language, so we often don't think of a "build process" for Ruby gems, because it is missing that compile step.

That said, when we build gems there's usually a defined sequence of steps to perform before releasing that gem. Here's an example of what I'm currently doing:

- Update my Gem version number (via a rake task)
- Run unit tests
- Run static analysis tools such as code coverage tools
- Package the gem
- Deploy the gem to the relevant repository.

What are your build processes for Ruby gems? Are there steps I'm missing that are commonly performed when building gems?

Comment: You should give bundler a try. It covers 3/5 in your list. For unit tests give CI a go. Bundler: http://railscasts.com/episodes/245-new-gem-with-bundler TravisCI: https://travis-ci.org/

Answer (score 1):

Definitely [use bundler to create the gem](http://railscasts.com/episodes/245-new-gem-with-bundler). This will give you rake tasks to automate most of the process.

Also, use a CI server like [Travis](https://travis-ci.org) to automate the testing process.  You could also use [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) to get a whole host of tools like coverage metrics, etc.

By using those tools, my gem release process is:

```
rake release
```

And it gets built and [published to](http://guides.rubygems.org/publishing/#rubygems-org) [rubygems.org](http://rubygems.org) for public consumption.